# converting c++ DTW code to java

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

I want to translate a code from C++ to Java. The original code implements fast DTW algorithm. The piece of code I couldn't figure out was `I` attribute I'm not sure what it does hence, I can't convert it.

The error in Java is in statements `l_buff+I` & `u_buff+I` because the plus operator is not supported between `int I` & `double[] l_buff,u_buff`.

I have included all statements that involves `I`

```
int  I;
for(i=0; i<ep; i++)
{
    /// A bunch of data has been read and pick one of them at a time to use
    d = buffer[i];

    /// Calculate sum and sum square
    ex += d;
    ex2 += d*d;

    /// t is a circular array for keeping current data
    t[i%m] = d;

    /// Double the size for avoiding using modulo "%" operator
    t[(i%m)+m] = d;

    /// Start the task when there are more than m-1 points in the current chunk
    if( i >= m-1 )
    {
        mean = ex/m;
        std = ex2/m;
        std = Math.sqrt(std-mean*mean);

        /// compute the start location of the data in the current circular array, t
        j = (i+1)%m;
        /// the start location of the data in the current chunk
        I = i-(m-1);
        lb_k2 = lb_keogh_data_cumulative(order, tz, qo, cb2, l_buff+I, u_buff+I, m, mean, std, bsf);
```

and the `lb_data_cumlative` method implementation is

```
public static double lb_keogh_data_cumulative(int[] order, double []tz, double []qo, double []cb, double []l, double []u, int len, double mean, double std, double best_so_far )
{
    double lb = 0;
    double uu,ll,d;

    for (int i = 0; i < len && lb < best_so_far; i++)
    {
        uu = (u[order[i]]-mean)/std;
        ll = (l[order[i]]-mean)/std;
        d = 0;
        if (qo[i] > uu)
            d = dist(qo[i], uu);
        else
        {
            if(qo[i] < ll)
                d = dist(qo[i], ll);
        }
        lb += d;
        cb[order[i]] = d;
    }
    return lb;
}
```

here is the paper on which the code relies [SIGKDD TRILLION](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/SIGKDD_trillion.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`l_buff+I` and `u_buff+I` mean that you shift the beginning of the arrays to `I` elements. The  `lb_keogh_data_cumulative` parameters `l` and `u` won't see the first `I` elements of the given arrays.

So you could write something like

```
lb_k2 = lb_keogh_data_cumulative(order, tz, qo, cb2, Arrays.copyOfRange(l_buff, I, l_buff.length), Arrays.copyOfRange(u_buff, I, u_buff.length), m, mean, std, bsf);
```

The arrays are not modified by the called method so you can pass a copy.